# Getting email of an user depending on a select input

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I use `firebase` for user authentication. I have a form where user can log in. There is a `select` input with different `options`. User chooses one `option` and types correct `password` and gets logged in. I need to find the current user that has been chosen in a `select` input, so then I can use it in a `onSignIn()` method - to be precised: `this.$store.dispatch('signUserIn', { //CURRENT email: this.chosenUser.email, password: this.password})`.

This somehow works but when I click `Log in` in my actual `firebase` connected project I get an error: `signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument "email" must be a valid string.` I thougth that `this.chosenUser.email` is a string. How do I fix it?

Here goes a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/j4wx6rzlzw).

SignIn component:

```
<template>
  <section class="signin">
    <div class="login">
      <h1>Log in</h1>
      <form>
        <select v-model="chosenUser">
          <option v-for="user in users">{{ user.login }}</option>
        </select>
        <input type="password" v-model="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="button" @click="onSignIn" value="Login">
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
import { mapGetters } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chosenUser: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSignIn() {
      this.$store.dispatch("signUserIn", {
        email: this.user.email,
        password: this.password
      });
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["users", "user"])
  }
};
</script>
```

Store.js:

```
state: {
    users: [
      { login: "London", email: "london@gmail.com" },
      { login: "Paris", email: "paris@gmail.com" }
    ],
    user: null
  },
  actions: {
    signUserIn({ commit }, payload) {
      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(payload.email, payload.password)
        .then(user => {
          const newUser = {
            id: user.uid,
            cart: []
          };
          commit("setUser", newUser);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    setUser(state, payload) {
      state.user = payload;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    users: state => {
      return state.users;
    },
    user: state => {
      return state.user;
    }
  }
```

Comment: why is the select input not linked with any model? how do you get the selected user?

Comment: Just a typo, in a demo there is a v-model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bind value to select:

```
<select v-model="chosenUser">
  <option v-for="user in users" :value="user">{{ user.login }}</option>
</select>
```

If you don't bind value, the default value will equal to option's `text`

Default data should be an object

```
data() {
    return {
      chosenUser: { login: "London", email: "london@gmail.com" },
      password: ""
    };
}
```

In methods:

```
 methods: {
    onSignIn() {
      this.$store.dispatch("signUserIn", {
        email: this.chosenUser.email,
        password: this.password
      });
    }
  }
```